# Using a server as a docker proxy

Tags: docker

I'm wondering if the following concept is possible:

I've got a docker registry with images and I've got few servers that I want them to be able to pull images but not directly from the docker registry. I would like to have another server which will be the docker proxy and this server will be the only one which will have access to the docker registry, the other servers will use this server to download images.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a reverse proxy. Docker Docs has some articles on the subject, for nginx and/or apache.

https://docs.docker.com/registry/recipes/apache/
https://docs.docker.com/registry/recipes/nginx/

This may be used for authentication, rate limiting, proxy buffering and many other features included in nginx/apache.

This setup is not uncommon, and not exclusively for hosting a Docker Registry.